# the millisUntilFinished of my countdown timer would not change according to user input

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Here is my problem:
I get user input from two numberPickers. I then use the collected number to set the `millisInFuture` of my countdown timer. But the problem is: whatever number I choose, the `millisUntilFinished` of my countdown timer would not change according  to user input.
My code is simplified as follows:

```
int firstMin = 1;
int firstSec = 30;//initial value in the field
int i = 1; //to determine whether the remained time should be shown

private void initFirstMinPicker() {
    minPicker.setMaxValue(60);
    minPicker.setValue(firstMin);//set the current value of number picker

    minPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            firstMin = newVal;//pass the selected int to firstMin

        }
    });


//My countdown timer is supposed to start on clicking a button
firstTimer = new CountDownTimer(firstMin * 60000, 500) {//use 500 to 
avoid skipping the last onTick()
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onTick:firstMin " + firstMin);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                workLeft.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }
            i++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
```

My TAG:

```
D/TAG: onTick:firstMin 6
D/TAG: onTick:firstMin 6
D/TAG: onTick:firstMin 6
```

It's clear that `firstMin` has been changed, but when I use `firstMin * 60000` as an argument, the `millisUntilFinished` will always start from 60000 regardless of how much `firstMin * 60000` evaluates to. That is, when my countdown timer begins to count down, it always count downwards from 60(initial value of firstMin * 60). I have no idea why this should happen. Have you guys ever come across such a problem? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only declaring `firstTimer` once, meaning that it'll only ever be created when `firstmin = 1`. You'll need to create a new instance of `firstTimer` whenever `onValueChanged` is called, for example:

```
minPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        firstMin = newVal;//pass the selected int to firstMin
        firstTimer = new CountDownTimer(firstMin * 60000, 500) { ... }
    }
});
```

It might also be worth creating a function that returns a new `CountDownTimer`, taking only the value of `firstMin` and automatically populating the rest of the default values, to save on unnecessary code repetition.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much. And I will give your suggestion a try, too :)